# Копирование файла в Ansible между двумя удаленными серверами

Tags: ansible, rsync

Нужно скопировать файл с одного удаленно сервера на второй.
Если на обоих серверах команда выполяется от одинаковых пользователей, то все корректно копируется, если же пользователи разные, то скопировать не получается.
Исходные данные:

```
ServerA - user: ubuntu
ServerB - user: user1

  tasks:    
    - name: Copy Remote-To-Remote (from serverA to serverB)
      synchronize: 
        dest: /tmp/from_serverA 
        src: /Project30-staging/to_serverB
        #set_remote_user: yes
        use_ssh_args: yes
        mode: pull
      delegate_to: serverB
      environment:
        GIT_SSH_COMMAND: ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
```

Пробовал разные вариации с параметрами вида:

`rsync_opts: "--rsh='/usr/bin/ssh -l ubuntu'"`
Тоже пока не выходит

Comment: А как у вас ansible узнаёт, на какой сервер с каким пользователем ходить?

Comment: В inventory или `host_vars` задан правильный `ansible_user` для каждого хоста? (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_inventory.html#list-of-behavioral-inventory-parameters)

Comment: Пробовали посмотреть как Ansible запускает `rsync`, запуская плейбук с `-vvv`?